# Allow edition of questions referring to Unity having [Unity3d] tag?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Serving the queue of suggested edits, found many places where people are suggesting edits where every ocurrence of *Unity3D* is replaced with *Unity* on the question title or text, saying that unity3D is the site name and the SO tag, but the engine is called Unity.

Would that conflict with the tag and with the intention when the ambiguous tag was changed?

Comment: IMO, that seems to be taking the "don't use tags in the title" guideline a tad to literal. This change does not make questions easier to find, if I search for "unity" I still get hits with Unity3d in the title.